# Identify certain words in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tsv file as follows.

```
id    ingredients    recipe
code1  egg, butter   beat eggs. add unsalted butter
code2  tim tam, butter  beat tim tam. add butter
code3  coffee, sugar   add coffee and sugar and mix
code4  sugar, fresh goat milk   beat sugar and milk together
```

I want to remove the entries if they contain the below mentioned words in either `ingredients` or `recipe` column.

```
mylist = ['tim tam', 'unsalted butter', 'fresh goat milk']
```

My output should look as follows.

```
id    ingredients    recipe
code3  coffee, sugar   add coffee and sugar and mix
```

Is there a way to do this using pandas? Please help me!

Comment: Can you show us the work you have done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `contains` with `join` to look to see if string contains a "sub" string, and join base with '|' to make a regex:

```
mylist = ['tim tam','unsalted butter','fresh goat milk']
df[~(df.ingredients.str.contains('|'.join(mylist)) | 
     df.recipe.str.contains('|'.join(mylist)))]
```

Output:

```
     id    ingredients                        recipe
2  code3  coffee, sugar  add coffee and sugar and mix
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster solution is join columns together first and then check values by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df = df[~(df['ingredients'] + df['recipe']).str.contains('|'.join(mylist))]
print (df)
      id    ingredients                        recipe
2  code3  coffee, sugar  add coffee and sugar and mix
```

Another solution:

Use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for both columns, then chain by `|` and inverse mask with `~`:

```
m1 = df['ingredients'].str.contains('|'.join(mylist))
m2 = df['recipe'].str.contains('|'.join(mylist))
m = m1 | m2
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

df = df[~m]
print (df)
      id    ingredients                        recipe
2  code3  coffee, sugar  add coffee and sugar and mix
```

**Timings**:

```
#[40000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [358]: %timeit df[~(df['ingredients'] + df['recipe']).str.contains('|'.join(mylist))]
10 loops, best of 3: 47.8 ms per loop

In [359]: %timeit df[~(df['ingredients'].str.contains('|'.join(mylist))|df['recipe'].str.contains('|'.join(mylist)))]
10 loops, best of 3: 78.2 ms per loop
```